# Querying from dynamically-populated drop down list using ArcGIS API for JavaScript:

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Using ArcGIS API for Javascript 4, I want to create a drop-down list in the view that is dynamically populated based on the values available in a layer. When users select a value from this drop down and click a button, I want to query those features matching the value in the drop menu and have them appear on the map.

I've combined some elements from the following two tutorials for this:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/tasks-query/index.html
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/featurelayer-query/index.html

I can get the attributes to populate in the drop down list. However, clicking the button to query returns the following error message: "Promise rejected: Cannot perform query. Invalid query parameters."

I'm hoping this is just something simple I've overlooked, but I can't seem to find the issue. I am copying and pasting the complete code in case that's easiest to drop into CodePen or elsewhere to work with.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>

    <title>Project viewer</title>

    <style>
      
      html,
      body,
      #mainViewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      #optionsDiv {
        background-color: dimgray;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 90%;
      }
      
      #drop-downs {
        padding-bottom: 15px;
      }
      
      widget {
        /* Fill in later to style drop down widget */
      }
      
    </style>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
     href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.15/"></script>

    <script>
       require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/Basemap",
        "esri/widgets/LayerList",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/PopupTemplate",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
        "esri/tasks/support/Query"
        ], function(
          Map,
          MapView,
          Basemap,
          LayerList,
          FeatureLayer,
          PopupTemplate,
          GraphicsLayer,
          QueryTask,
          Query
        ){
        
         var basinUrl =   "https://services.arcgis.com/v01gqwM5QqNysAAi/arcgis/rest/services/Chesapeake_Bay_major_watersheds_feature/FeatureServer/0";
         
         //* for drop down
        var basinTypeSelect = document.getElementById("MajBas");
       
        //* Define the popup content for each result
        var popupTemplate = {
          title: "{MajBas}",
          fieldInfos: [
            {
              fieldName: "MajBas",
              label: "Major basin"
            }
          ]
        };       
         
        // Layer - project footprints
       const basinLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        url: basinUrl,
        outFields: ["*"],
        visible: false
        });
 
        // Layer - dark nav basemap 
       const basemap = Basemap.fromId("streets-night-vector");
         
       //** Point querytask to project boundary URL
        var qTask = new QueryTask({
          url: basinUrl
        });
 
       //** Set the query parameters to always return geometry and all fields.
       //** Returning geometry allows us to display results on the map/view
        var params = new Query({
          returnGeometry: true,
          outFields: ["*"]
        });
         
       //* GraphicsLayer for displaying results
       var resultsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
       
       var map = new Map({
           basemap : basemap,
          layers: [basinLayer]
       });

        var mainView = new MapView({
          container: "mainViewDiv",
          map: map,
          popup: {
            highlightEnabled: false,
            dockEnabled: true,
            dockOptions: {
              breakpoint: false,
              position: "top-right"
            }
          },
          center: [-75.325395, 40.306275],
          zoom: 5
        });
       
         // add widget with drop-down options
        mainView.ui.add("optionsDiv", {
          position: "bottom-left"
        });
         
         //* query all features from the basin layer
        mainView
          .when(function () {
            return basinLayer.when(function () {
              var query = basinLayer.createQuery();
              return basinLayer.queryFeatures(query);
              document.getElementById("doBtn").addEventListener("click", doQuery); 
            });
          })
          .then(getValues)
          .then(getUniqueValues)
          .then(addToSelect)
          .then(doQuery)
         
         //* return an array of all the values in the
        //* basin name field
        function getValues(response) {
          var features = response.features;
          var values = features.map(function (feature) {
            return feature.attributes.MajBas;
          });
          return values;
        }
         
        //* return an array of unique values in
        //* the MajBas field of the basin layer
        function getUniqueValues(values) {
          var uniqueValues = [];

          values.forEach(function (item, i) {
            if (
              (uniqueValues.length < 1 || uniqueValues.indexOf(item) === -1) &&
              item !== ""
            ) {
              uniqueValues.push(item);
            }
          });
          return uniqueValues;
        }
       
         //* Add the unique values to the basin type
        //* select element. This will allow the user
        //* to filter basin by name.
        function addToSelect(values) {
          values.sort();
          values.forEach(function (value) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = value;
            basinTypeSelect.add(option);
          });
    
        }
         
        //** Call doQuery() each time the button is clicked
        mainView.when(function () {
          mainView.ui.add("optionsDiv", "bottom-left");
          document.getElementById("doBtn").addEventListener("click", doQuery);
        });

        //**
        var attributeName = document.getElementById("MajBas");

        // Executes each time the button is clicked
        function doQuery() {
          // Clear the results from a previous query
          resultsLayer.removeAll();
          // Build new query
          params.where =
            "MajBas =" + attributeName.value;

          // executes query and calls getResults() once promise is resolved
          // promiseRejected() is called if the promise is rejected
          qTask.execute(params).then(getResults).catch(promiseRejected);
        }

        // Called each time the promise is resolved
        function getResults(response) {
          // Loop through each results and assign a symbol and PopupTemplate
          var basinResults = response.features.map(function (feature) {
            // Sets the symbol of each resulting feature
            feature.symbol = {
              type: "simple-fill", 
              color: [212, 161, 87, 0.25]
            };

            feature.popupTemplate = popupTemplate;
            return feature;
          });

          resultsLayer.addMany(basinResults);

          // print the number of results returned to the user
          document.getElementById("printResults").innerHTML =
            basinResults.length + " results found!";
        }

        // Called each time the promise is rejected
        function promiseRejected(error) {
          console.error("Promise rejected: ", error.message);
          }         
         
      
        
       });
       
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="mainViewDiv"></div>
    
    <div id="optionsDiv">
      <h2>Example</h2>
        <div id="drop-downs">
          <b>Basin</b>
        <br/>
        <select id="MajBas" class="widget"></select>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <button id="doBtn">Search</button> <br />
      <p><span id="printResults"></span></p>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

"MajBasin" is the name of the field in the attribute table containing the basin names that are visible in the drop down.

Answer (score 1):

When setting params.where, the field name before the attribute value was missing. Thus, the updated code that builds a working query is:

```
params.where =
            "MajBas =" + "'" + basinTypeSelect.value + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

I populated the dropdowns by reading a json file.